# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'

Tags: python, suds, nonetype

So initially I connect to a server with:

```
soapclient = Client(url, transport=WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username=user, password=passwd))
```

and this works fine because when I print it it shows all of its properties correctly.

Then I run:

```
request = self.soapclient.factory.create('ns3:CRRequest')
request['ChangeRequestId'] = '601904'
response = self.soapclient.service.GetChangeRequestById([request])
```

And then I get an error on the response line which reads:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nlujan\Desktop\prism_source.py", line 63, in <module>
   CR = prism.getChangeRequestById('601904')
File "C:\Users\nlujan\Desktop\prism_source.py", line 36, in getChangeRequestById
  response = self.soapclient.service.GetChangeRequestById([request])
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
  return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 643, in send
  result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 678, in succeeded
  reply, result = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 149, in get_reply
  soapenv.promotePrefixes()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'
```

I had someone else run my script and it works fine on their computer but I keep getting an error in mine. I've installed several different versions of python to see if that's the problem but with no luck. Does anyone see what could be the problem?

Comment: What version of suds are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an endpoint address

```
client = Client('url', location = "https://someurl/services")
```